# Yum repo with python 2.6 on Centos7

Tags: linux, centos, python, yum, node.js

I need to run Nodejs 4 on a CentOS 7 machine. I have a limited internet access on this machine and basically can only hit Yum repositories (I can add new ones).
Since Nodejs 4 is not available even in EPEL, I am using a private Yum repo with Nodejs 4 wrapped in an RPM. I have not created this RPM and can't change it.
The problem is - the mentioned Nodejs 4 RPM has indirect dependency on Python 2.6 exactly (indirect as dependency of dependency needs this version of Python). Now Python 2.6 is not available in any Centos 7 yum repo (not even in EPEL), the only versions available to me are: 2.7.5 and 3.4.3. And Thus the installation of the said Nodejs 4 RPM fails:

```
Error: Package: nodejs4-runtime-4.4.2-22.el6.x86_64 (nodejs4)
       Requires: python(abi) = 2.6
       Installed: python-2.7.5-34.el7.x86_64 (@bertinet-base-7)
           python(abi) = 2.7
           python(abi) = 2.7
       Available: python34-3.4.3-4.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           python(abi) = 3.4
```

Like I said, I do not have internet access except for Yum repositories. Do not ask me why, it is not my decision, I can't change this.
I need Nodejs 4 on this machine.
Is there any trusted Yum repo out there for Centos 7 that provides either: Nodejs 4 or Python 2.6? Thanks.

Comment: I wonder how is the access limited to random (new ones can be added by user) yum repos (which are `http(s)`) while not allowing other https...

Comment: The "machine" is deployed in the cloud. One of the deployment steps is to add yum repos I want to use on the "machine" to the system that creates and deploys it. The system that creates the "machine" will restrict all internet access from this "machine", with exception of the configured yum repos. Imagine some kind of "parental control" you set-up for your kids on your antivirus - blacklists certain websites. Except this whitelists certain urls. There :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodejs4-runtime-4.4.2-22.**el6**.x86_64 - installing package for EL6 on EL7 will not work.

Get a package for el7 for example from [here](https://rpm.nodesource.com/pub_4.x/el/7/x86_64/) however this may conflict with nodejs from other sources.

The [instructions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#enterprise-linux-and-fedora) on node site are clear enough.

Anyway this looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561962/install-nodejs-4-on-redhat

Comment: Thanks. This however won't work for me. Like I have said, I do not have internet access to curl nodesource. I would need a yum repo with the RPM in there.

Comment: I actually followed these instructions on a VM with internet access and realised that the script basically adds appropriate yum repo. I copied the details including the GPG key and voila, I can now install nodejs 4. Thanks man!